# reseult set in jtable

Tags: java, database, swing, postgresql, jtable

I m trying to execute query with a string added at last.. and I am unable to do it with `resultset` so i tried `preparedstatement` Im able to insert into query.. but unable to get its result :( please help me. here is my sample code

```
PreparedStatement pstm;
String query= "SELECT C.name, C.searchkey, F.product, 
                F.lastsoldqty, F.consumption, F.lastsaledate,F.deliverydate,
                F.remainderdate, F.remark1, F.remark2, F.stock, F.invoiceno, 
                F.id FROM followup F,customers C where C.ID=F.CUST_ID 
                AND C.searchkey= ?";
         pstm= connection.prepareStatement(query);
         pstm.setString(1, number);
         pstm.executeQuery();
      //   System.out.println("executed");
         java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd1 = pstm.getMetaData();
         int colNo = rsmd1.getColumnCount();       
         DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
         int rowCount = model.getRowCount(); 
         for(int i = rowCount -1; i >= 0; --i) { model.removeRow(i); } 

          while(pstm.next())   //im getting error here cant find method .next in pstm
             {

                  Object[] objects = new Object[colNo];
                 for(int i=0;i<colNo;i++){

                         objects[i]=rs.getObject(i+1);

                 }                  
                 model.addRow(objects);

             }
```

Comment: You can use `model.setRowCount(0)` to remove all the rows in the model.

Comment: that is not my question.. the question is how do i get the resultset

Comment: y is this question -1?

Comment: I know it is not your question. I was just giving you a tip. I didn't downvote the question but it was probably downvoted because you didn't search the forum or the API yourself. There are plenty of examples in the forum that show you how to use a PreparedStatement and/or create a TableModel from an SQL query.

Comment: ok thnx, but yea.. i looked forums. resultset to execute query and prepeared statement is for update query. but was unable to find how to use both

Comment: A PreparedStatment can be used for any SQL request. It just allows you to easily format the request because it worries about building the query with the parameters provided so you are less likely to make syntax/format errors with the query.

Comment: What do you mean is there any way? When you execute a PreparedStatement it returns a ResultSet. If your ResultSet is empty then your query is wrong. Why don't you start with a simple query like "select * from SomeTable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Familiarize yourself with the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

The method [`next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) is defined for `ResultSet` not `PreparedStatement`. Use

```
ResultSet resultSet = pstm.executeQuery();
```

then

```
while (resultSet.next())
```

Comment: this is not working for me. it is not even getting the query into resultset

Comment: Does the query work when run from the Postgresql SQL client? Don't you need a `JOIN` when doing a `SELECT` across 2 tables...